# if else statement for radiobuttongroup

Tags: if-statement, radio-button

In radio button group, how do you set up an if else statement if the user didn't select any answer and just clicked on the Show Me the Answer button? If he didn't select any answer, the correctRect (a rectangle to highlight the text) must still show up but not the wrongRect (right now the wrongRect shows).

Comment: Show us what you tried .Some code will be get you help

Comment: What language / platform???

Comment: I use flash cs3 action script 3.0

Comment: if (cdlCorrect[index] == 0) {// Correct answer is the 1st radio button

correctRect.graphics.drawRect(45, 50, rectSize, 25);

trace("This is 1st Radio button");

else {// This code is the same as the green, except we fill the box with RED (wrongRect)

trace("User Selected the WRONG Answer");

if (cdlUserAnswers[index] == 0) {

correctRect.graphics.drawRect(45, 50, rectSize, 25); rectSize:width 50:height

trace("This is 1st Radio button");